# capture apps when file is being used by another proc

Tags: process

I have a build server that throws "the file is being used by another process" from time to time. I get alerting by email but by the time I log onto the machine to investigate, the file isn't used anymore. Is there a monitoring tool that detects the exeption occurred by scanning event log and at the moment capture what process has handle on the file?

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: 2008 r2 server...